# Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar' SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, procedure

I have a problem with code in SQL Server. The error is:

> Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

My code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION porcentajeCadaUno  -- Se ingresa las variables del procedimiento almacenado para calcular % --
    (@cantidad INT,
     @idEvento BIGINT)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST((@cantidad) * 100 AS FLOAT) / 
           (SELECT (dbo.cuentaPersonasConEvento_Leidos(@idEvento))) 
END

CREATE PROCEDURE porcentajeCadaCampoTabla
    @nombreCampoTabla NVARCHAR(100),
    @idEvento BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX), @params BIGINT

    SET @params = @idEvento

    SET @stmt = 'select [' +@nombreCampoTabla +'],count(['+@nombreCampoTabla+']), 
dbo.porcentajeCadaUno (count(['+@nombreCampoTabla+']),@params) from Invitado as inv inner join 
(select idInvitado from Invitado intersect select idInvitado_FK from Leido) as le on  le.idInvitado=inv.idInvitado
where inv.idEvento_FK=@params group by ['+@nombreCampoTabla+']'

    EXEC sp_executesql @stmt, @params
END

EXEC porcentajeCadaCampoTabla 'generoInvitado', 1
```

I expect that the output show me a table with 3 columns, the first, name of variables, the second (how many), and the third the percent.

Comment: `'[' +@nombreCampoTabla +']` is **not** injection safe! Just like when you inject a statement when using a literal string for a "parameter"  (you can escape the value by using `'`), you can do the same with an object name (using a `]`). If you *need* to use dynamic objects, then use `QUOTENAME`; as it'll escape any characters (so a value like `'test]; DROP TABLE [test]'` would become `''test]] DROP TABLE [test]]]'`.

Comment: The error, however, is telling you the error; `@Params` is expected to be an `nvarchar`, and you have a `bigint`. [sp_executesql (Transact-SQL): Examples - A. Executing a simple SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql#a-executing-a-simple-select-statement)

Answer (score 3):

`sp_executesql` needs 3 parameters here: SQL statement, parameter declaration, and the parameter value. Below is an example, where I've added the `QUOTENAME` function to ensure identifiers are properly enclosed and escaped:

```
SET @stmt = 'select ' + QUOTENAME(@nombreCampoTabla) +',count('+QUOTENAME(@nombreCampoTabla)+'), 
dbo.porcentajeCadaUno (count(['+@nombreCampoTabla+']),@params) from Invitado as inv inner join 
(select idInvitado from Invitado intersect select idInvitado_FK from Leido) as le on  le.idInvitado=inv.idInvitado
where inv.idEvento_FK=@params group by '+QUOTENAME(@nombreCampoTabla)+';';

EXEC sp_executesql  @stmt, N'@params bigint', @params = @idEvento;
```

Comment: I think there is a small error in `QUAOTENAME(@nombreCampoTabla)`, +1 from my side.

Comment: @Zhorov, I fixed the typo in my example. There are other errors in the query but I think this example should get you going.